# Dúvida sobre indexes para campos booleanos - MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Tenho documentos com campos booleanos numa coleção do Mongo. Para indexar esses campos, é melhor que seus valores sejam Number (0 ou 1) ou não faz diferença se forem do tipo booleano? Tenho recebido alguns alertas de "slow query" na busca por usando esses campos booleanos.

Answer (score 1):

No final das contas o índice vai ficar com duas entradas (0 e 1 ou true e false) creio que não faça diferença. Sem dúvida os valores booleanos vão ocupar menos espaço em disco, o que vai te deixar com um índice menor e dados menores.

Os avisos de consulta lenta devem ser por outro motivo. Você tem mais filtros na consulta além desse campo booleano? em que ordem você criou os campos do índice? tem ordenação na consulta? Adiciona um exemplo de consulta que ficou como lenta, e mostra a estrutura do teu documento que fica mais fácil de ajudar.